# PyInstaller Tkinter window low resolution in App bundle, but not in app program

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, pyinstaller

I think I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure it out myself.

I'm building a Mac App from Python 2.7 using PyInstaller (running the dev3.3 version). The app works fine, no issues. At the beginning there's a small window for updates which is built using Tkinter.

After building the app with PyInstaller (running the oneflie option) I get two files( `ls -al` outcome):

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 karoldra  staff  62756614  8 lis 11:08 mac
drwxr-xr-x   3 karoldra  staff       102  8 lis 11:09 mac.app
```

Here's the structure of that folder:

- mac
- mac.app

  - Contents

    - Frameworks
    - Info.plist
    - MacOs

      - mac
    - Resources

      - MyIcon.icns

Basically - the mac.app package contains exactly the same mac file as the main folder.

The issues is that I get a different resolution in my Tkinter window depending on which file I actually run. Here's a sample of the Tkiter window:

- the top one is run from the `mac` file
- the bottom one is run from the `mac.app` file

[image]

As you can see the bottom ones resolution is much lower for some reason...

Can somebody tell me why this is happening and how to solve this issue?

Comment: what code is in `mac` and `mac.app` ? `mac.app` is directory - what do you have in this directory ?

Comment: bottom app looks like screenshot, not a real application.

Comment: This is exactly the problem - the bottom image looks like a screenshot, but it's not ... :(

Comment: I would say: if it looks like screenshot so it has to be screenshot. I don't have Mac to run it and see on your own.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer by...carefully reading the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-options-for-a-mac-os-x-bundle) ;) There's this one line which solve my problem:

***For example, when you use PyQt5, you can set NSHighResolutionCapable to True to let your app also work in retina screen***

In case someone else is seeing this problem on MacOs here's the answer:

My spec file was missing the High Resolution setting specified by the `info_plist` parameter. Here's an example:

```
app = BUNDLE(exe,
     name='myscript.app',
     icon=None,
     bundle_identifier=None
     info_plist={
        'NSHighResolutionCapable': 'True'
        },
     )
```

Hope it will help someone else too!!! :)

Comment: You have a misplaced comma. Should be "bundle_identifier=None, info_plist={'NSHighResolutionCapable': 'True'})". Other than that, good work and thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Comment: where did this setting should place?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasted a lot of time before I found your thread...
@NicholasJela, in .spec file, according to Pyinstaller manual:
https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files